# Подмена http трафика ( ответа с сервера) для приложения

Tags: http, wireshark, fiddler, remote-debugging

Всем привет!
Недавно задался вопросом , можно ли обойти активацию приложения при помощи серийника ( проверка через интернет)
Заметил, что запрос осуществляется по по протоколу http (без шифрования)
Знаю данные, которые нужно отправить программе , чтобы она активировалась.
НО
Проги по типу FIDDLER, Charles , HTTP toolkit не видят трафик, исходящий не из браузеров!
Возможно ли подменить трафик? Есть ли проги под win?

Comment: Нужно заплатить.

Comment: Можно подменить запись в hosts файле для домена и перенаправить все на localhost. А там запустить https://pypi.org/project/pretenders/ и сконфигурировать, чтоб отвечал так как нужно